# ArrayList Grouping and Sum

Tags: java

How to from a list :

```
PojoA | child1 | aChildy | 1
PojoA | child3 | aChildz | 5
PojoA | child2 | aChildw | 4
PojoB | child4 | aChildw | 2
PojoB | child2 | aChildy | 3
PojoC | child2 | aChildz | 8
```

Grouping By child, aChild and sum last column ?

Java 8 grouping concatenation seems doesnt work. My POJOs is :

```
class Pojo{
 UUID id;
 Child child;
}

class Child{
 UUID id;
 AnotherChild aChild;
}
```

`groupingBy(s -> s.getChild())`, `groupingBy(s -> s.getChild().getAnotherChild())` : `concat` grouping doesn't work. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did use classic loop for{ if..else }